# Is Touch supported in ContextMenu in DataGrid in WPF app?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, datagrid, touch, contextmenu

I have a DataGrid in my WPF application. I have defined a ContextMenu for the rows in the grid. When we right click on the grid's row, context menu appears but it doesn't come up when we "hold & press" on a touch support device (i.e. tablet with Windows 7). I have set `IsManipulation=true` in my grid.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Shared="False" x:Key="contextDailyPlannerMenu">
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding ViewCustomerCommand}" Header="View Customer" />
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding DisplayOrderCommand}" Header="Order Guide" />
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="DailyPlannerGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding ListDailyPlanner}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextDailyPlannerMenu}" HIsManipulationEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" >
```

Will touch be supported by default? If not, how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you set Stylus.IsPressAndHold?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.ispressandholdenabled.aspx